# Multiplication of Radical Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This might be a duplicate question, if so please close. There is this math technique that is (I think taught in Algebra) for solving a specific type of problem.

An example would be the following:

$ { \sqrt{t-5} + 5} \over {\sqrt{t-5} - 5}$

If I remember correctly it has something to do with multiplying both sides by the denominator:

$ { \sqrt{t-5} + 5} \over {\sqrt{t-5} - 5}$ * $ { \sqrt{t-5} + 5} \over {\sqrt{t-5} + 5}$

Or something like this...

What is this called and is this the correct way to solve this? I am pretty sure it is a basic technique.

Comment: It's called "rationalize the denominator by multiplying numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator."

Comment: Ah, perfect - just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "rationalize the denominator by multiplying numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator."